# Any concrete book for renormalization to recommend？

Tags: reference-request, textbook-recommendation, renormalization

Any  concrete book for renormalization to recommend？ concrete Enough，and simple enough， both in mathematics and physics.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are at least two *very* different approaches to renormalization in physics; the very meaning of "renormalization" is quite different in relativistic quantum field theory versus statistical mechanics (although obviously there are connections).  What references might be useful depend a great deal on what kind of problems you might be interested in.

Comment: Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62770/what-mathematical-treatment-is-there-on-the-renormalization-group-flow-in-a-spac

Comment: @Buzz, renormalization in relativistic quantum field theory is what I want  to know.